# Angular 5 HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get some data from my server via HttpClient Post request.
the request completes well. it returns the desired data. this process is handled by a service. this service in turn returns the data to the method calling from a component.
 the problem here is the service receives the data successfully but the method calling the service does not receive the data in the first request. it does receive the data from the second request onwards. I dont understand why. can someone make the component receive the data in the very first request?

Here is the code

**AuthorizationService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ServerResponse } from './login/server-repsonse';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  response:ServerResponse;
  public obtainAccessToken(user):ServerResponse{   

   this.http.post<ServerResponse>("/login",user,httpOptions).subscribe(
     data=> {
       this.response= data;
    console.log("In the service....");
    console.log(this.response);
    },
     err=>{ console.log(err)},
     ()=>{console.log("Success")}
   );  

   return this.response;
  }

}
```

**LoginComponent.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  private user = new User();

  private serverResponse: ServerResponse;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {

    this.serverResponse = this.authenticationService.obtainAccessToken(this.user);
    console.log("In the login component....");

    console.log(this.serverResponse);
  }
}
```

**[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAD8h.png)**

Comment: Try this: move `return this.response;` to the line just below `this.response= data;`  in the `obtainAccessToken` function in your service. I am certain that having the return outside of the subscribe is the problem. The data isn't available the first time because the call is async, but is in subsequent calls since you are storing the results in a class level variable.

Comment: It does the same even after following your advice.

Answer (score 2):

@Arul, In general, the services must be return only an observable (we not subscribe in the service, we subscribe in the component)

```
//your service
public obtainAccessToken(user):ServerResponse{   
   //just return a "observable"
   return this.http.post<ServerResponse>("/login",user,httpOptions)
}

//Your component
//Your component is who take account of the observable
login() {
    this.authenticationService.obtainAccessToken(this.user).subscribe(res=>{
       this.serverResponse=res;
       console.log(this.serverResponse) //<--here have value
});
   console.log(this.serverResponse); //Outside subscribe have NO value
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because of javascript's asynchronous functions, your `obtainAccessToken` called before getting response from server,
you should use [promises](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises/) for your services .

Comment: It's true that we can convert a Observable to Promise, and it's true that when we start with Angular we tending to convert Observable to Promises. But It's more "natural" work with Observables.

Comment: @Eliseo i thought promise handles a single event when we have an async operation and observable is like a stream and allows to pass zero or more events where the callback is called for each event. so i thought it's better to use promises in this case.

Comment: Observable it's used to handle a single event too. Always we make an httpClient.get or httpClient.post really happens one time (and Angular's team choosed that httpClient return Observables). it's the reason I **personally** consider more "natural" work with Observables (i don't want to say that I have reason)

Comment: @Eliseo I myself am new to angular and worked with both promise and observable and prefer promise i think it was easier for me to implement, but you are right i will try to work with observables more.